Gorm preload doesn't follow the Join conditions
So I'm trying to make a complex queries with a lot of joins and nested structs. I need to load the structs but Preload is not following related Joins with their conditions and its keep doing its own queries.
How can I make this work?
My joins are pretty complicated and I don't want to do the same join twice.

type Assetinfo struct {
    Uid           string
    MapPolicyApps []MapPolicyApps `gorm:"foreignKey:app_id;references:uid;AssociationForeignKey:pol_id"`
}
type MapPolicyApps struct {
    Id           int
    PolID        string       `gorm:"column_name:pol_id;foreignKey:Uid"`
    PolicyPolicy PolicyPolicy `gorm:"foreignKey:Uid;references:PolID;AssociationForeignKey:uid"`
    AppType      string    // This can be application or category
    AppId        string    `gorm:"column_name:app_id;foreignKey:Uid"`  // this can be app id or application id (bad naming i know)
    Asset        Assetinfo `gorm:"foreignKey:AppId;references:Uid"`
    CreatedAt    string
}

type PolicyPolicy struct {
    Uid               string `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    IsEnabled         bool
    MapPolicyProfiles []MapPolicyProfiles `gorm:"foreignKey:PolID;references:Uid"`
}

var assets []*Assetinfo 

err := Db.Table("application_application apps").
    Select("Distinct apps.*, apps.avatar as icon, profile_asset.address as ip, apps.is_health_check as is_need_request").
    Joins("LEFT JOIN map_policy_identities ON map_policy_identities.assign_type = 'user' AND map_policy_identities.assign_id = ?", userid).
    Joins("LEFT JOIN policy_policy ON map_policy_identities.pol_id = policy_policy.uid AND policy_policy.is_enabled = true").
    Joins("LEFT JOIN map_policy_apps ON map_policy_identities.pol_id = map_policy_apps.pol_id").
    Joins("LEFT JOIN map_category_apps ON map_category_apps.category_id = map_policy_apps.app_id").
    Joins("LEFT JOIN map_app_assets ON apps.uid = map_app_assets.app_id").
    Joins("LEFT JOIN profile_asset ON profile_asset.uid = map_app_assets.asset_id").
    Where("map_policy_apps.app_id = apps.uid OR apps.uid = map_category_apps.app_id").
    Where("apps.is_enabled = true AND apps.is_visibled = true").
    Preload("MapPolicyApps.PolicyPolicy.MapPolicyProfiles.ProfileAddr").
    Preload("MapPolicyApps.PolicyPolicy.MapPolicyProfiles.ProfileTimerange").
    Preload("MapPolicyApps.PolicyPolicy.MapPolicyProfiles.ProfilePosturecheck").
    Find(&assets).Error


And Gorm can't load the structs without Preload, So if it's possible to load all nested structs with joins and without Preload, I would appreciate to know how.
